# Visual Studio 2015 update 1 frozen on launch

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash

Been running vs 2015 with no issues. Installed update 1 yesterday and the ide no longer launches. There are no relevant entries in event viewer, and no error is shown. Task manager shows the ide is still running (for over 10 minutes at high process priority). Add Programs and Features does not show Update 1 as an item. Tried a repair yesterday as I was leaving the office to no avail. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Uninstalled VS 2015. Reinstalled VS 2015 with Update 1 checkbox turned on. 2 hours later, all is well.